# ERROR: column specified more than once in Postgres

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql, postgresql-8.4

I am a Postgres newbie and i have the following table to create through c# code:

```
string create = "CREATE TABLE " + articles
                    + "("
                       + " SEQU_NK SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,"
                       + " ARTICLE_NK bigint   NOT NULL,"
                       + " DEPOT_NK  bigint  NOT NULL  ,"
                       + " EXPED_NK  bigint NOT NULL,"
                       + " CLIENT_NK  bigint  NOT NULL,"
                       + " SIGNE_TRANSP character varying(2) NOT NULL,"
                       + " NB_PLIS_TOTAL bigint DEFAULT 0  ,"
                       + " DH_PREM_ETIQUETTE timestamp  DEFAULT '0001-01-01 00:00:00',"
                       + " DATE_DEPOT_ARTICLE character varying(10) DEFAULT NULL,"                    
                       + " ARTICLE_NK character varying(10)  references articles(ARTICLE_NK),"
                       + " DEPOT_NK character varying(10)  references depots(DEPOT_NK),"
                       + " EXPED_NK character varying(10)  references expeds(EXPED_NK),"
                       + " CLIENT_NK character varying(10)  references clients(CLIENT_NK),"
                    + ") ";
```

The also try to write query on PGAdmin3 :

```
CREATE TABLE articles( SEQU_NK SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
                       ARTICLE_NK bigint   NOT NULL,
                        DEPOT_NK  bigint  NOT NULL  ,
                        EXPED_NK  bigint NOT NULL,
                       CLIENT_NK  bigint  NOT NULL,
                        SIGNE_TRANSP character varying(2) NOT NULL,
                        NB_PLIS_TOTAL bigint DEFAULT 0  , 
                        DH_PREM_ETIQUETTE timestamp  DEFAULT '0001-01-01 00:00:00',                      
                        ARTICLE_NK character varying(10)  references articles(ARTICLE_NK),
                        DEPOT_NK character varying(10)  references depots(DEPOT_NK),
                        EXPED_NK character varying(10)  references expeds(EXPED_NK),
                       CLIENT_NK character varying(10)  references clients(CLIENT_NK)) ;
```

And error obtained is :

```
ERROR:  column "article_nk" specified more than once
********** Error **********

ERROR: column "article_nk" specified more than once
SQL state: 42701
```

How to fix this error as it is a foreign key? As I am changing the query from Mysql to Postgres?

The equivlaent Mysql query is (which I am translating to Postgres is):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `articles` (
  `SEQU_NK` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Auto: Numero sequence',
  `ARTICLE_NK` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `DEPOT_NK` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `EXPED_NK` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CLIENT_NK` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `SIGNE_TRANSP` varchar(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `NB_PLIS_TOTAL` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `DH_PREM_ETIQUETTE` datetime DEFAULT '0001-01-01 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`SEQU_NK`),
  KEY `ARTICLE_NK` (`ARTICLE_NK`),
  KEY `DEPOT_NK` (`DEPOT_NK`),
  KEY `EXPED_NK` (`EXPED_NK`),
  KEY `CLIENT_NK` (`CLIENT_NK`),

) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=18 ;
```

Comment: The problem is that you are declaring `ARTICLE_NK` as a bigint THEN as a `character varying(10)`. Use two different name

Comment: I assume he wants `KEY `ARTICLE_NK` (`ARTICLE_NK`),` not the column...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have columns:

`ARTICLE_NK bigint   NOT NULL,`

and

`ARTICLE_NK character varying(10)  references articles(ARTICLE_NK)`

postgres interprets second as a column. not as a key...

You should use this syntax instead:

`CONSTRAINT ARTICLE_NK_FK FOREIGN KEY (ARTICLE_NK)
      REFERENCES articles (ARTICLE_NK)`

[CREATE TABLE manual with some examples](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html)

Comment: Why you changed ARTICLE_NK to ARTICLE_NK_FK ..Is it fine if i do "CONSTRAINT ARTICLE_NK  FOREIGN KEY (ARTICLE_NK)
      REFERENCES articles (ARTICLE_NK)"

Comment: naming convention - better use unique name for every object

Comment: But i am asked to do PostGRE conversion of the schema given to me in MySql(autogenerated). So i am afraid if the naming convention changed the column name mismatch..

Comment: nd it also don't contain haracter varying(10) datataype in query

Comment: in your MYSQL code `KEY `ARTICLE_NK` (`ARTICLE_NK`)` stands for `FOREIGN KEY` not for the coulmn name. it does not participate in DML statements, so FK name does not matter

Comment: if you don't want to read documentation before you start using a product - use code'n fix strategy - rewrite your statement as I shown you and try running your queries against created table - see if they are what you expect to see...

Comment: Ok thanks... could you please give me any link of best doumentation you know about postGre ?

Comment: sure - I'd start from official reference on `CREATE TABLE` command. added to answer...